# Trouble With SimpleCursorAdapter and Importing to Listview

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm at a bit of a loss here why my listview won't populate with my simple database info. Any help would be greatly appreciate. Is there something wrong with my SQL statement?
I was under the impression that it was correct, but I guess that my cursor could be bad. Or maybe my simplecursoradapter doesn't make any sense (I realize that it's deprecated, but thought that it could still work)

```
package com.example.firstdatabase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view_test);

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FunnyNames (Email VARCHAR, FirstName VarChar, LastName VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO FunnyNames VALUES('hello@aol.com', 'Jeff', 'Bath');");

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT Email FROM FunnyNames", null);
        cur.close();
        db.close();
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                cur,
                new String[] {"1"},
                new int[] {R.id.textView1}

                );

        listview.setAdapter(sca);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

here is my listview XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="307dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />


</LinearLayout>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. The cursor adapter needs a live cursor and database. In this code you're closing the cursor and database before passing the cursor to the adapter.
2. The cursor you pass to `CursorAdapter` must include a column named `_id`.
3. Use [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to manage your databases, especially override its `onCreate()` to create and populate your databases. For example, now you get a new row of data in your database every time you activity `onCreate()` is called (e.g. app launched or device orientation changed).

Answer (score 0):

If your using SimpleCursorAdapter to populate listview, your cursor should have "_id" as a column.

please modify your
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FunnyNames (_id integer primary key autoincrement,Email VARCHAR, FirstName VarChar, LastName VARCHAR);");

please refer link for further clarification

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#DisplayResults